# Console App that scans for changes in a directory past 24 hours (CLOSED)

Tags: c#, logging, filesystems

I'm creating a program that scans for changes, not create or delete, in ALL the files in a given directory, and all of his sub directories, in the past 24 hours.
I've seen lots of other examples/tutorials but not all of them do what I'm looking for.

This is my code so far:

```
using System.IO;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"C:\Path");
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(myDirectory);
    DateTime from_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    DateTime to_date = DateTime.Now;
    var files = directory.GetFiles()
                         .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= from_date && file.LastWriteTime <= to_date)
                         .ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The problem is that the code above only tells me the last change in the directory. What I want is a log of all the changes in the directory.

I am a learning student, so lots of explanation would be great! :)

I am NOT, I repeat NOT, looking for FileSystemWatcher, I don't want my server to stay on for 24 hours straight. I want to start this program once every 24 hours, make a log, close it.
If anyone can help me out with this, or at least give me something to start with, I would very much appreciate it!

**EDIT**

I finally my goal to work via another code, a whole different code.
I want to thank you all for helping me and raising up my understanding of a couple of things

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Neither files have log of changes nor OS writes such log. Only information you can get is a last write time. If you need whole log, then you should create it manually (e.g. create windows service with `FileSystemWatcher`), or you can consider to use some [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), which tracks all changes to files (in this case changes to files should be done though version control software).

Comment: Is it perhaps possible then to get the last write time of multiple files? Because I've tried something in that particular direction and I've only gotten 1 last write time. Not multiple.

Comment: You can get only last write time for each file. Single DateTime value. Not list of dates when file was modified.

Comment: Well that is just too bad. But it is possible to get the lastwrite of every file right? I mean by literally giving every file his own code? I know this is nto the perfect way, but is this possible?

Comment: @vascomakker sorry, don't get what you mean by giving every file his own code. You can get last write time of each file in directory. That is what you actually doing now

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky When I debug the code, it only gives me the most recent changed file out of all those folders. I just want what you just said: "last write time of each file in directory".

Comment: @vascomakker your code should give all files which have last write date in specified range. Probably you have only one file which matches that criteria

Answer (score 0):

Without a `FileSystemWatcher` you would have to have an external file which you would use to compare differences.

So on first run you would get

File 1
File 2
File 3

No changes!

Next run you might get

File 1
File 3
File 4

and you would be able to compare the first list to show that File 2 is missing and File 4 is new...

Answer (score 0):

As others have already written: Without a file system watcher or storing a list of files you have no chance to detect deleted files. Also it is possible to change the file date (however, I do not know whether it is possible to change last write time or only create time). Also renaming a file usually does not change any file date.

> The problem is that the code above only tells me the last change in the directory

I tested your code in VS 2010, and in the debugger I see multiple entries in the variable files. Maybe you only have one modified file in the directory itself and the other changed files in sub directories (see belov)? Maybe your output is wrong?
If you really have multiple recently changed files in the directory, I'd suggest to use an additional variable for intermediate results to check where the error occurs. (Does directory.GetFiles() give you an incomplete file list or is there a problem with the filter in where?)

Last but not least, you write

> and all of his sub directories

According to MSDN GetFiles only returns the files in the current directory. If you also want sub directories, you have to recurse into them. Of course you should address the problem of incomplete file list before adding recursion.

Hope that helps

Comment: All it gives me is the most recent changed file. But I understand that is not possible to log every last write date of the files? I mean like in the past, not in the future with a filesystemwatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, this may (as far as I know) not even be possible to do cleanly in .NET - what you're really looking for could be done using a [File System Minifilter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which runs in kernel space quietly and can intercept all [IRP packets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) within a certain filepath (e.g. C:\Sub*). Such a program can be loaded using [fltmc.exe command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).